# civicrm volunteer error

Tags: civivolunteer

Keep seeing this error: getFieldValue failed

CRM_Core_Exception: getFieldValue failed in .../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/Options.php on line 93

Also, i cannot perform the extensions db upgrade...

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling civicrm volunteer extension through extension interface and by hand.
I've tried upgrading civicrm to latest

any advice on how to resolve this error is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! It would be helpful if you could edit your question to include the versions of CiviCRM, WordPress and CiviVolunteer that you have installed. This will help others to provide better answers.

Comment: I have the same issue. CiviCRM 5.34.0 WordPress 5.7 CiviVolunteer 2.4.1